# Cant change memory usage in R

Tags: r, memory

I am trying to change the memory usage for R on a windows 7 machine.
I go to the desktop shortcut > properties and try to change the target from 
`"C:\Program Files\R\R-2.13.0\bin\i386\Rgui.exe"` to 
`"C:\Program Files\R\R-2.13.0\bin\i386\Rgui.exe" --max-mem-size=500M`
as per this post https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-June/241154.html

But I get an error message "The name '"C:\Program Files\R\R-2.13.0\bin\i386\Rgui.exe" --max-mem-size=500M' specified in the target box is not valid, make sure the path and file name are valid."

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that the file exists in this location?

Comment: yes - because the shortcut C:\Program Files\R\R-2.13.0\bin\i386\Rgui.exe works OK

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it. It works fine on my machine. Maybe you entered the `--max..` in the "execute-in"-field instead of the "target"-field. If this is not the problem try this: create a .bat file and enter `yourpath\Rgui.exe --max-...`, then create a shortcut to that .bat.

Comment: I checked and I am entering it in the target field. I tried the .bat approach - It runs with just "C:\Program Files\R\R-2.13.0\bin\i386\Rgui.exe" but will not start with "C:\Program Files\R\R-2.13.0\bin\i386\Rgui.exe" --max-mem-size=500M. The DOS window just flashes up and then closes.

Comment: I have now solved this - thanks for your help - I retyped the --max... rather than cutting and pasting and it worked.